# How to check if a record exists for just a specific user?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Right now in my POST route, I have this:

```
post '/states' do
  if logged_in? && params[:state_name] != ""
    @state = State.find_or_create_by(:state_name => params[:state_name])
      if @state.users.exists?
        "You have already added this state."
      else
        @state.users << current_user
        redirect "/states"
       end
```

If a user adds the same state twice, they get the error message and it does not add a duplicate to the database. Great, but when a NEW user adds the same state, they get the same error message. How do I check if the record exists just for the current_user? If it doesn't exist, I want the current_user to be added to @states.users.

I've tried a bunch of different things but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: How are `State` and `User` related? Might make more sense to make the validation `scope` based but I would need to understand the relationship to explain where to put this. Something akin to `validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :state_name }` or the reverse `validates :state_name, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }` or using a join table `validates :state_id, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is...

```
  if @state.users.include? current_user
    "You have already added this state."
  else
```

Comment: Why would you need to re-save the `@state`? `@state.users << current_user` adds to the JOIN table; this already persists the changes.